# Is it possible to publish an update to an iOS app without the original private key?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to update a live application in the iOS App Store if the original private key used to sign the app the first time round has been lost? What are the ramifications of revoking the current distribution certificate and creating a new one based on a newly generated key pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the private key, but yes you can revoke the certificate and create a new one with a new key pair.

Comment: Ok so if I revoke the current certificate & create a new one based on a newly generated key pair I can happily push an update to the current app without ever needing the original private key?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I had to do this once all you have to do is revoke it and use the new one.